# Apache FOP: Set base path url for accessing web ressource

Tags: java, xslt, apache-fop

I'm stuck with accessing a image from external resource.

My structure is the following, i have three projects, backend, frontend and a common project. The backend and the frontend holds the data for the pdf generation. These data would be passing to the common and there it would be generate.

Now i need to set a coverpage-image. The image is located under the webApp directory of the backend and frontend:

```
- webApp
|- ui-resources
 |- pics
```

in java i do the following:

```
final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
fopFactory.setBaseURL(StringUtils.stripStart(basePathUrl + PDF_BASE_PATH_EXTENSION, "/"));
final FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
foUserAgent.setBaseURL(fopFactory.getBaseURL());
```

the `basePathUrl` variable is a value given from the properties file, there is something like that: `http://127.0.0.1/8080` and the constant `PDF_BASE_PATH_EXTENSION` is that: `/ui-resources/pics`.

and in the xsl file i do the following:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url(pdfLogo.png)" content-width="60mm" content-height="30mm"/>
```

but that's not working, my idea was that i can access the image in the xsl like the html do it with css.

If i "hardcode" it in the xsl like this:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('http://127.0.0.1:8080/ui-resources/pics/pdfLogo.png)" content-width="60mm" content-height="30mm"/>
```

then i get the following exception:

```
ERROR org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent - Image not available. URI: http://127.0.0.1:8080/ui-resources/pics/pdfLogo.png. Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for http://127.0.0.1:8080/ui-resources/pics/pdfLogo.png (No context info available)
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for http://127.0.0.1:8080/ui-resources/pics/pdfLogo.png
```

And i can verify tht i have access to the image with this url.

If i change the basePathUrl in the java code to this:

```
String basePathUrl = servletRequest.getRealPath("");
```

then it runs on locale (eclipse) but not on server the basePathUrl would be `null`.

Anybody an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't closed the string quote in `<fo:external-graphic src="url('http://127.0.0.1:8080/ui-resources/pics/pdfLogo.png)">`

Comment: this won't fix the error